reactive picklist
does anyone know or have already made a reactive picklist? When you select the value of the field, another value is shown in the other. In this case, show the value of the product chosen from the picklist


Did you check the picklist module on Trailhead? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/picklist_admin
Perhaps consider combining it with a formula field?

Sorry I expressed myself wrong, in this case it would be a picklist with a choice which in this case are the product IDs and the pick list shows the names of the products
